# Does static has special meaning in Java Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Recently,I meet a weired problem when I exercise in Leetcode
The problem is [Print in Order](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/).My Soulution is below

```java
class Foo {

    private  static boolean firstFinished=false;
    private static boolean secondFinished=false;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public Foo() {

    }

    public void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (lock) {
            // printFirst.run() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
            System.out.print("first");
            System.out.println(firstFinished);
            printFirst.run();
            firstFinished = true;
            lock.notifyAll(); 
        }
    }

    public void second(Runnable printSecond) throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (lock) {
            while (!firstFinished) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            System.out.print("second");
            System.out.println(secondFinished);
            // printSecond.run() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
            printSecond.run();
            secondFinished = true;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void third(Runnable printThird) throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (lock) {
           while (!secondFinished) {
                lock.wait();
            }

            // printThird.run() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
            printThird.run();
        } 
    }
}
```

It couldn't pass the test case.But when I change **firstFinished** and **secondFinished** to non-static,it passed all the test case.I don't know what happened to it.I print the value of firstFinished and secondFinished before I assign True value to them,and it seems like they become true before I assign to them.Can anyone tell me what happened?Does static has some special meaning in Java Threads?

[image: Result]

Comment: "*Does static has special meaning in Java?*" - It has a meaning, otherwise it would be pointless to have the keyword, wouldn't it? Its semantics is that a static method or field binds to the class itself, not to its instances. This means that if something is `static`, it is shared across all instances of the class.

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html. After you've read that, think about what happens is Leetcode creates more than one instance of your Foo class. to execute the test multiple times. What will happen on the second test?

Comment: @JBNizet In  problem description，he says "The same instance of Foo will be passed to three different threads. "But it shouldn't change the static variable value before I assign to them.I 'm not very familiar with MultiThreads.Could you explain it more detaily？

Comment: One test will use one instance of Foo and pass it to 3 threads. But that doesn't mean that Leetcode (or, more realistically, an application), won't do that repeatedly, i.e. have a loop that creates a Foo, passes it to three threads, and verifies that the outcome is correct every time. Have you read the page I linked to? What would be your answer to the question I asked you?

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica I searched some thing about static meaning in Java Threads,But the result I got is static means it binds to class not object,but it still couldn't solve my problem,In Multi-Threads ,When you use static,you couldn't pass the test but when you use non-static it pass.I don't think the reason is static bind to class not object

Comment: @JBNizet So,it means i change the variable value in the first test case, so in the second test case it will still be true because it's static

Comment: Exactly. In general, mutable static variables are a huge code smell.

Comment: @Turing85, Sure, "static" has meaning, but its meaning is not _changed_ by the use of more than one thread.

Answer (score 0):

*At in the `first runnable class` try to avoid `.notifyall` for example:*

```
public void first(Runnable printFirst) throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (lock) {
            // printFirst.run() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
            System.out.print("first");
            System.out.println(firstFinished);
            printFirst.run();
            firstFinished = true;}

           // if class notify then only it has to give descending order, try it this way.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I think JBNizet has been explained very well,and the problem is not call notifyAll or not.